# How to search a word in a file and replace the entire line with a new line?

Tags: python

I have a file (with extension.hgx) that has some data like this:

```
length             =  0.00000783
height             =  48
RATIO              =  2
X                  =  1.0
Y                  =  1.0
```

I would like to open the file and replace the two lines:

---

```
height             =  48
RATIO              =  2
```

---

With:

---

```
height             =  8
RATIO              =  8
```

---

I tried parsing the file and could search for the "height" and "RATIO". Unfortunately, I could not replace the line with new line and re-save the file. In my case the problem is that, that in the file the value of parameters e.g. height(=48) varies and sometimes has uneven spaces in between. I want to replace this complete line with--
 height             =  8

I have written the following code

```
import fileinput
import sys
f = open('test.hgx','r')
line_num = 0
search_phrase = "height"
for line in f.readlines():
    line_num += 1
    if line.find(search_phrase) >= 0:
        print line_num

newline='height                  =  8'
lnum=1
for line in fileinput.FileInput("test.hgx",inplace=1):
    if lnum==line_num:
        result = newline+"\n"
    else:
        result=line
    lnum=lnum+1    
    sys.stdout.write(result)
    print line
```

This does not help replace complete line and save the file again. returns empty file.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Ris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?

```
with open('test.hgx') as f:  lines = f.read().splitlines()
with open('test.hgx', 'w') as f:
  for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('height') or line.startswith('RATIO'):  
      f.write(line.rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + ' 8\n')
    else:
      f.write(line + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to stop iterating in the first loop after finding the "height" line:

```
if line.find(search_phrase) >= 0:
    print line_num
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use regex tool:

```
import re

regx = re.compile('^(([^ \t]+)[ \t]+=.+)',re.MULTILINE)

new = '''\
RATIO              =  8
sdjlkhbfvjhdbfjhsdoijhfsdhfksdhfh
height             =  8
'''

dic = dict(mat.group(2,1) for mat in regx.finditer(new))

regchange = re.compile('^('+'|'.join(dic.iterkeys())+')[ \t]+=[^\r\n]+',re.MULTILINE)

with open(filename,'r+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    f.seek(0,0)
    f.write(regchange.sub(lambda m: dic[m.group(1)],content))
    f.truncate()
```

You put in **new** the lines you want to take place in the file, no matter in which order (that's why I wrote 'RATIO' line before 'height' line in my exemple, to show)

The program manages to obtain the dictionary **dic** that is used to create the regex that allows to search for the lines to be replaced and to substitute them with lines recorded in **dic** as values corresponding to the first name of the line

The line 'sdjlkhbfvjhdbfjhsdoijhfsdhfksdhfh' has no importance. I put it in new to show that the regex **regx** matches only with lines of the format 'name   = something'

This code should work as-is. You have just to give a file's name to **filename**; If any error, give it please.